First call to rand after calling srand doesn't look random at all
I'm getting strange behavior out of the rand() function in C.  The result of the first call to rand() after srand() looks very predictable and un-random.  I tried both with the seed from 0 to 10, and using the system time as a seed and sleeping 1 sec after each call to srand, produced similar results:  the output is almost a linear function of the seed.
EDIT:  I changed my test program so that the first call to rand after calling srand, determines how many times rand is called to generate the result.  Following is first the original program with seed 0-10 and its output; then, the modified program with seed 0-10 and its output.
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned int randnum, ind;
  char line[130]; 

  for (ind=0; ind <=10; ind++) {
    srand(ind);
    randnum = rand();
    printf("%u, %u, %u, \n", ind, randnum, rand());
  }

  gets(line);
  return 0;
}

Output:
0, 38, 7719,
1, 41, 18467,
2, 45, 29216,
3, 48, 7196,
4, 51, 17945,
5, 54, 28693,
6, 58, 6673,
7, 61, 17422,
8, 64, 28170,
9, 68, 6151,
10, 71, 16899,

The result increases by 3 or 4 when the seed is incremented by 1.
Now, the modified program and its results:
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned int randnum, nreps, ind1, ind2;
char line[130], ok; 

for (ind1=0; ind1 <=25; ind1++) {
    srand(ind1);
    nreps = rand() % 11;
    for (ind2=1; ind2 <= nreps; ind2++) rand ();
    randnum = rand();
    printf("%u, %u, %u \n", ind1, nreps, randnum);
}
gets(line);
return;
}

Output:
0, 5, 8365
1, 8, 24464
2, 1, 24198
3, 4, 23577
4, 7, 10960
5, 10, 28321
6, 3, 5206
7, 6, 11794
8, 9, 4670
9, 2, 22398
10, 5, 6722
11, 8, 28519
12, 0, 5628
13, 4, 30076
14, 7, 12236
15, 10, 28761
16, 2, 27002
17, 6, 15290
18, 9, 3191
19, 1, 209
20, 4, 24795
21, 8, 32575
22, 0, 14808
23, 3, 16714
24, 6, 27567
25, 10, 29202

That looks much better!

you should put srand outside of your loop, actually you only want to call this once in your application, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand

Side note: Never use gets().

Only call srand once in your program. Every time you call it you reset the seed, and similar seeds could lead to similar sequences.

On a couple of different notes, please try to indent your code, in a consistent way. That will make it much easier to read and follow. Also don't include header files you don't need. For your programm all you need is <stdlib.h> (for srand and rand) and <stdio.h> (for printf and gets (which as mentioned you should avoid)).

I don't think these dupe targets are appropriate. You'd see the same behavior if these 10 srand calls had been made across 10 runs of the program, and these aren't all the same seed, so the "why do I get the same numbers with the same seed" target isn't a good fit either.

"Doesn't result in a random number". None of them do – they are a repeatable sequence of pseudorandom numbers produced by a defined algorithm.

Calling srand once per program execution doesn't eliminate these kinds of problems. For example, if you call srand with the system time as a seed, but your program is scheduled to run at consistent times, you can end up with unwanted correlations in random number sequences between runs.

Yes, I know that srand is only supposed to be called once.  But the point is, the first call to rand after calling srand doesn't give a random number.  So rand doesn't seem to be working well.
So, is there some way to call srand, or rand, so that it will generate (pseudo)random numbers?  Does my second call to rand generate (pseudo)random numbers?

@lorasaur you need to call srand with some pseudo random value like the current time, typically srand(time(NULL));. If you call srand with the same argument, you'll get the same sequence of pseudo random numbers each time. Read this

The reason you don't like your first pseudorandom number is that your seeds are terrible. Almost every bit is zero. PRNGs can only work with the entropy you give them initially, and your seed has almost none.

Looks like your compiler is using a LCG with m == 2^31, a == 2144013, c == 2531011, and outputting bits 30 to 16 (ie: "Microsoft Visual/Quick C/C++"). See https://ideone.com/dnzTaf

There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced. Implementations may be crappy. If you need quality, get a PRNG with the properties you need. The glibc one seems to be nicer.

This behavior makes difference in how rand() is used.  The first time I used it about a year ago, it was to place notification windows at a random position.  I used time as the seed, and I was taking the ratio of rand() divided by RAND_MAX.
But this resulted in notifications at a similar time being almost on top of each other.
So, I used the modulus operator instead of taking the ratio.  Now I need rand for something else.
With seeds that are close together, apparently you'd have to call rand() multiple times.  The first time maybe to determine how many times it's called, mod 9.

CALL srand() ONCE Sorry (not sorry) for yelling :-)

@pmg you should have told them to call srand(time(NULL)) once, because by callingsrand(<some fixed value>) once, you probably (maybe even certainly, not quite sure) will get the same sequence on every program run.

@Jabberwocky: if your implementation does not change between runs (no OS/libraries update, no compiler updates/changes. etc) calling srand() with a fixed value will repeat the same values obtained from rand(); by design (See eg C11 7.22.2.2p2: "... the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. ...").

That's very useful when proving and debugging. I usually comment out the srand(time(NULL)) so that the behaviour is repeatable, until it's ready to move on.

Note that OP is repeatedly calling srand() for testing purposes.


First call to rand after calling srand doesn't look random at all


The result of the first call to rand() after srand looks very predictable and un-random. Is this how rand() is meant to work?

Yes, the upper bits look predictable on your machine, yet the C standard library rand() is weakly defined.  What you see is a certain possibility with a compliant compiler and library.
: Is 9,9,9,9,9,9 ... random?


Does the second call to rand() actually generate a (pseudo)random number?

Yes as did the first.  Some implementations of rand() do suffer from needing a few rand() calls before they look random.
It is all very implementation dependent.


Using the system time as a seed and sleeping 1 sec after each call to srand, produced similar results. Is this how rand() is meant to function?

Yes.  Once seeded, rand() is specified to produce the same result regardless of the time elapsed between calls.   If no srand() call occurs before rand(), rand() acts as if srand(1) had first occurred at program start.
Would need to see OP's true code for more detail.
Below is a common initialization.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
   unsigned seed = (unsigned) time(0); 

   // Maybe something to avoid same time in 2 quick program calls 
   seed ^= (unsigned) getpid();  // Non standard function.

   srand(seed);
   ...
}


I had expected the first call to rand() after srand to generate a number that isn't a simple function of the seed. But it's close to being a linear function of the seed.

Yes some srand()/rand() routines are very simple - to the point of discouraging their use.
Thus serious random number use obliges other code.
Some srand()/rand() implementations are better.
My GCC produced the below.  Since rand() is usually about bits, the below uses 0x%08X to better illustrate.  Also consider that RAND_MAX may be as small as 0x7FFF (32,767), which apparently is so in OP's case.  This is another hint to OP's hobbled srand()/rand() implementation.
RAND_MAX = 0x7FFFFFFF
 0, 0x226E5331, 0x4A656E89
 1, 0x6B8B4567, 0x327B23C6
 2, 0x59B997FA, 0x67A3797F
 3, 0x47DB4E3A, 0x1CCC40D1
 4, 0x754E7DDD, 0x11265233
 5, 0x232ADD1B, 0x05F2A7DD
 6, 0x11560EBD, 0x7B33BFB9
 7, 0x3E52DFF5, 0x6F19E243
 8, 0x2D274378, 0x65114598
 9, 0x1A7DD803, 0x5989B872
10, 0x486C7C6F, 0x4E32F398


Aside: gets() is no longer, since C11, part of the C standard library.  Best to not use it, even with older code.

I modified my test program so it now prints out betterpseudorandom numbers with seed 0-25, and I edited the original post to include the updated test program and its results, after the original program and its results.

@lorasaur What version of C are you using?  If C99 or later consider timespec_get().  Use something like struct timespec ts = { 0, 0 }; timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC,); unsigned seed = (unsigned) (ts.tv_sec ^ t.tv_nsec); srand(seed); to potentially use a finer clock for initialization.

I'm using the "cl" command in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022.  So that's probably capable of very recent versions of C.
I tried it and it does produce results that aren't obviously an almost-linear function of the seed - even when I didn't call Sleep between calls to srand.  So thanks for the suggestion :)

@lorasaur "that's probably capable of very recent versions of C" --> Try printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__); to report the version of C.

The compiler says "STDC_VERSION" is an undeclared identifier (I did include the underscores in the program).  It doesn't matter much to me, though.  Using timespec_get is a good solution that works in my environment.  For portability, what I did works better.

@lorasaur you appear to be using Microsoft's compiler.  They're the kings of backwards compatibility, so you won't see changes just for the sake of being modern.  For example their RAND_MAX is only 32767 because 40 years ago their int type was only 16 bits.

@MarkRansom Possible that MS may have an agenda here, yet "RAND_MAX is only 32767" in itself is not really a sign of low quality.  I suspect that their rand() generates the same sequence (maybe LCG) as it did many years ago instead of better current alternatives.  For me, srand(unsigned), the limiting initialization to UINT_MAX + 1 different sequences is certainly a weakness in the C srand() design regardless of RAND_MAX.

@MarkRansom  Makes me wonder if a srand_mt(size_t n, unsigned char data[n]) that then use MT for subsequent rand() could save us from the limited initialization options?

@chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't mean to use Microsoft's RAND_MAX of 32767 as a sign of low quality, just a sign that they hadn't changed rand in 40 years.  To substitute something newer and better would break compatibility, and that's something they avoid for good reason.  If you want something better you need to move on from rand, which is much easier if you use C++ because better stuff like MT is included in their random library.

@MarkRansom  Good thoughts, yet "To substitute something newer and better would break compatibility".  True about potential break yet not something a user should rely so heavily on in select cases.  Consider some <math.h> function that provides a better (lower ULP error) yet different, or in this case rand(), a sequence that is more random.  Given MS still has Feb 29, 1900 - I guess they value consistency over correctness - even though wrong and prefers to perpetuate the error. I leave you for the last word if desired.

@chux-ReinstateMonica funny story about Feb 29 1900: My First BillG Review by one of the founders of StackOverflow.  It's all a matter of priorities, and prioritizing backwards compatibility has allowed Microsoft to become the behemoth that it is.

@MarkRansom  Thanks!  I didn't know C++ has a library with the Mersenne twister.  I'll look into that.   That sounds very portable to me, and switching to C++ shouldn't be a problem.

Most implementations of rand use a very primitive pseudo-random number algorithm called the Linear Congruential Generator (LCG) which has a strong correlation between the seed and the first number it generates.  There's no rule dictating it as the standard algorithm but you'll find it's almost universal.  There are plenty of better algorithms out there such as the Mersenne twister which you might be able to find in a library if this is important to you.  Otherwise I'd suggest just throwing away the first couple of generated numbers, the ones you see after that will look much more random.
srand(ind);
rand();
rand();
randnum = rand();



I'm getting strange behavior out of the rand() function in C. The result of the first call to rand() after srand() looks very predictable and un-random. Is this how rand() is meant to work?

Yes.  rand() generates sequences of pseudorandom numbers.  Such sequences are wholly deterministic, not random at all.  They are called pseudorandom because they (typically) vary chaotically over the function's range from one element to the next, similar to how a sequence of genuinely random numbers might do.  Although the C language spec leaves a lot of room for implementations to vary, note well these comments from its specifications for srand():

The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of
pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand. If
srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of
pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.

(C17 7.22.2.2/2; emphasis added)
That is, the sequence of numbers generated by rand() is wholly determined by the seed specified via srand().  Also, calling srand() multiple times restarts the sequence each time.
The appropriate usage, then, depends on your use case:

if you want genuinely random numbers, then use different functions.  The C specifications do not define such a function, but your OS may provide one.

if you want repeatable sequences of chaotically varying numbers then choose a seed value, and pass it to srand() each time you want to (re)start the sequence.  Read out the results via rand().  Not seeding at all is equivalent to seeding with 1.

if you want hard to predict sequences of chaotically varying numbers then seed, once per program execution, with a seed that tends to vary from run to run.  srand(time(NULL)) is a relatively common variation on that, but you can run into trouble with that if you launch multiple copies of your program at the same time.

if you want sequences that simulate a uniform probability density very well then consider dumping rand() in favor of a high quality PRNG that you provide (not necessarily write) yourself.  This can work around weaknesses in various C standard libraries' implementations of rand(), which aren't always as chaotic or unbiased as one might like.  For instance, some bits may be more chaotic than others.




I'm getting strange behavior out of the rand() function in C.

No, that's the intended behaviour.  The pseudo random number generator does a linear operation (this justifies the first result you get in the second column) with later truncation of several digits or mangling somehow the number digits (you cannot see this because you have provided only the first 10 seeds)  After you call rand(), you install the newly produced number as seed, so repeated calls to rand() (without intervening seed resets, as you do in the sample code) will produce a pattern that looks actually very random (while not being true random)  The truncation makes the nonlinear part of the algorithm, that results in a sequence of pseudorandom numbers each time you call rand() (but, as initialization routine, you have to call it only once, and initialize with a near random number -- like the microseconds part of the gettimeofday() routine)
The seed initialization allows you to produce the illusion of having true randomness, but also is open to make it repeatable (if you select a fixed number and use it in all experiments, you will get the same sequence each time you execute the program)
